# iOS Peripheral Mode Stop Advertising Doesn't Stop

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-bluetooth

I have a iOS objective-c app that acts as a peripheral. Everything works fine until I try to stop advertising. When I issue the following it just keeps advertising. I can even kill the app and it keeps advertising. The only way to stop it is to turn bluetooth off and back on manually in settings.

```
    if (_peripheralManager != nil)
        [_peripheralManager stopAdvertising];
```

_peripheralManager is defined as follows:

```
    CBPeripheralManager *_peripheralManager;
```

Comment: How are you seeing what is being advertised?  `stopAdvertising` will stop advertising services that you added to that specific peripheral manager instance but not stop the device as a whole advertising.  If you are still seeing the service you have added in your app then you should ensure that you haven't created multiple peripheral manager instances

Comment: I do experience the same problem.  Will you share you're whole scenario (how do you scan and detect the advertising is still ongoing, etc) and maybe if you found a solution?

Comment: @Paulw11 Same situation for me and if I set another string for CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey that's different than the one in system bluetooth settings, and then call startAdvertising on CBPeripheralManager instance `self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil]` for a while, then I call stopAdvertising method. During this process, I use another phone to scan for bluetooth device around. The new name set can be scanned forever unless I turn on/off bluetooth in system bluetooth settings or restart your phone.

Comment: The name isn't something you can really rely on. I have also seen names "stick". What you need to look for is the peripheral service you are advertising. You can check that with LightBlue app.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your timely reply. LightBlue is really a wonderful tool for bluetooth. I have checked its full services and find that the one set for data advertising is still there. After I switch off bluetooth in system settings, all of them can no more be scanned.